# Solving the ODE $w''(r) + \frac{1}{r}w'(r) - \frac{n^2}{r^2}w(r) = \frac{4\sqrt{r}}{n^2}(-1)^n $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we solve the ODE:

$$w''(r) + \frac{1}{r}w'(r) - \frac{n^2}{r^2}w(r) = \frac{4\sqrt{r}}{n^2}(-1)^n $$

I think the homogenous equation is of Euler type, and making the standard trial substitution, $t^{\mu}$, I found the complementary function to be:

$$ w_c(t) = c_1 r^n + \frac{c_2}{r^n}$$

Is it necessary to use a messy reduction of order to obtain the particular solution or are there any other possible methods?

Comment: i think it must be $\frac{1}{r}w'(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

The equation is
$$
r^2\,w''+r\,w'-n^2\,w=\frac{4(-1)^n}{n^2}\,r^{5/2}.
$$

Since $5/2\ne\pm n$, there is a particular solution of the form $A\,r^{5/2}$.

Comment: How did you make that last conclusion?

Comment: It is the _Indeterminate coefficient method_ for Euler's equation.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be much simpler than performing a reduction of order.